# I can't install ffmpegs (dependencies) - error with doxygen [mac 10.12.6 Sierra]

Tags: macos, cmake, ffmpeg, homebrew, doxygen

It installed about 70% of the dependencies it needed to get ffmpegs going, but it got stuck at installing 'doxygen'.

This is the error I got:

```
==> Installing dependencies for ffmpeg: doxygen, little-cms2, openjpeg, opus, rust, libgit2, cargo-c, rav1e, flac, libsndfile, libsamplerate, rubberband, sdl2, swig, llvm, snappy, speex, srt, leptonica, libb2, lz4, libarchive, tesseract, theora, x264, x265, xvid, docbook, boost, source-highlight, asciidoc, docbook-xsl, libyaml, ruby, asciidoctor, gnu-getopt, xmlto, libsodium, zeromq and zimg
==> Installing ffmpeg dependency: doxygen
==> cmake ..
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/macbook/Library/Logs/Homebrew/doxygen/02.make:
In file included from /tmp/doxygen-20220723-61533-5m5mdv/doxygen-1.9.4/src/outputlist.h:25:
/tmp/doxygen-20220723-61533-5m5mdv/doxygen-1.9.4/src/searchindex.h:29:10: fatal error: 'variant' file not found
#include <variant>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/doxymain.dir/__/generated_src/code.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/doxymain.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 46%] Linking CXX static library ../lib/libvhdlparser.a
cd /tmp/doxygen-20220723-61533-5m5mdv/doxygen-1.9.4/build/vhdlparser && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/vhdlparser.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /tmp/doxygen-20220723-61533-5m5mdv/doxygen-1.9.4/build/vhdlparser && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/vhdlparser.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar qc ../lib/libvhdlparser.a CMakeFiles/vhdlparser.dir/CharStream.cc.o CMakeFiles/vhdlparser.dir/ParseException.cc.o CMakeFiles/vhdlparser.dir/Token.cc.o CMakeFiles/vhdlparser.dir/TokenMgrError.cc.o CMakeFiles/vhdlparser.dir/__/generated_src/VhdlParser_adj.cc.o CMakeFiles/vhdlparser.dir/VhdlParserTokenManager.cc.o
/usr/bin/ranlib ../lib/libvhdlparser.a
[ 46%] Built target vhdlparser
make: *** [all] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


Error: You are using macOS 10.12.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.
```

Can someone please help me am not sure what it is, that I am supposed to do.

Comment: The last part ```Error:``` is clearly answered you what to do !!!.

Comment: if you are talking about the "you are using macOS 10.12" that's a programmed message that always come up when the OS is not updated and its an automated message, it literally has nothing to do with that, as they there are tons of other errors with the repo: 

Last 15 lines from /Users/macbook/Library/Logs/Homebrew/doxygen/02.make:
In file included from /tmp/doxygen-20220723-61533-5m5mdv/doxygen-1.9.4/src/outputlist.h:25:
/tmp/doxygen-20220723-61533-5m5mdv/doxygen-1.9.4/src/searchindex.h:29:10: fatal error: 'variant' file not found
#include <variant>

Comment: I guess the standard lib provided with your compiler is not fully C++ 17 compliant, since `variant` header is missing. Doxygen requires C++17: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/Release_1_9_4/CMakeLists.txt#L65-L67

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we're in the same boat. Fighting the "good fight", as it were.  We should probably both just bail to linux or even windows, because god knows they are going to keep making this hard for us....

However, probably like yourself, a combination of inertia and "good reasons" keeps us staying the course ;)

Basically, the issue is described correctly by the others here (lack of c++ 17 support) and in my case (and likely yours as well) is because gcc is a symlink to clang (9.0 if you are using the latest version compatible with our os)

Telling brew to use real gcc (I assume you have compiled it already, and if not - gcc 11.3.0 is a dependency for ffmpeg anyhow, so go ahead and build it; brew install gcc) can be done like this :

```
HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-11 HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-11 brew install doxygen
```

However, the above didn't work for me because - although it solved the c++ 17 issue, it exposed another problem :(

It seems that for some reason the minimum macos version number is messed up (I think because the sdk headers for 10.13 are installed with the latest version of xcode compatible with our os) and so the compilation fails.  Although there is almost certainly a better/cleaner way to deal with this issue, I solved it by manually compiling and installing doxygen after editing the code.

In the doxygen/filesystem/filesystem.hpp file around line 4491 you need to change the line

```
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 101300
```

to

```
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 111400
```

Then compile doxygen (extract the source from the brew cache), cd to the cmake folder then run

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/doxygen/1.9.4 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -Wno-dev -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-11 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-11

make
make install
brew link doxygen
```

Then continue the brew install ffmpeg.  I had trouble with nettle as well, and needed to compile and install that one manually too because the version of libcrypto packaged with macos (libressl) is incompatible.  I had to do the steps shown in "brew info openssl@1.1" in order to make sure the compiler used the openssl libcrypto that IS compatible and I couldn't figure out how to make brew do this for me.

Fun fun fun.  I am not all that hopeful that the rest of the compilation will go without issue, but it is chugging away again now.  I get the distinct impression that this is SO not worth the hassle/trouble.

Good luck!

** EDIT **

I'm still slogging through it, and it is taking a LONG time.  But as I encounter more issues I will try and detail them here with the hope that each issue I encounter is reasonably easy to overcome.

1. llvm failed to compile with lots of missing header errors.  Directing brew to use gcc-11 like i did with doxygen worked to compile it further (27%) but still failed (it looks like because it is calling clang specific options as a result of the brew cmake config passed to it... i'm still working on this one...)

Conclusion - I gave up.  It isn't worth the time in my view.

Instead I installed macports and used "sudo port install ffmpeg-upstream" to install ffmpeg-5.  Unless you have some dying need to compile yourself, I recommend you do this as well.

Comment: Damn man, I will try to follow your steps. But it should be doable. I have seen tons of developers using old macbooks, pro's and air's running all of these environments/libraries and dependencies, so I am sure, its all doable. 

Let me try and see how it goes, I will comment ASAP with my progress!

Answer (score 0):

I've spent quite some time to get around this issue as well and I ended up with another solution. I merely edited the formula to suit my needs :

```
brew edit doxygen
```

Once there, spot the "def install" block then edit the file so that it looks like this :

```
fails_with :clang
def install
  inreplace "CMakeLists.txt", "MACOS_VERSION_MIN 10.14", "MACOS_VERSION_MIN 10.11"
```

Save, exit.
In short, just add the "fails_with" line and the "inreplace" line. The first one causes brew to not use clang (so you need to have a gcc copy somewhere). This is to solve the C++17 issue. The second one patches the CMakeLists.txt file to allows cmake to do its magic. Once done, "brew install doxygen" should succeed.